# How to extract top records from a column based on category information of another column

Tags: sql

Here is a problem I cannot figure out. How to find recipients received totally $1024 within top three transfers.

```
create table transfers (
    sender varchar not null,
    recipient varchar not null,
    amount integer not null
);


insert into receivers values ("TFC", "Apple", 2014);
insert into receivers values ("TFC", "Google", 100);
insert into receivers values ("TFC", "Google", 345);
insert into receivers values ("Facebook", "Facebook", 834);
insert into receivers values ("Facebook", "Google", 56);
insert into receivers values ("VMware", "Google", 12);
insert into receivers values ("VMware", "Google", 300);
insert into receivers values ("Google", "Facebook", 20);
insert into receivers values ("Google", "Facebook", 100);
insert into receivers values ("Google", "Facebook", 1000);
```

P.S.
I was able to find the solution. 
The difficulty is how to get top amount records based on name. Instead of construct completed query, actually there are nice functions for it.

- In postgresql, fucntion OVER (PARTITION BY) is specially for this problem.
- In mysql, it is a bit harder, but you can use functions such as
  group_concat + substr, substr to combine records need to be sorted,
  then group_concat to inner sort.

Comment: Are looking to hire someone to do this for you?

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, get the top 3 `transfers` for each `recipient` based on `amount` and then check if the `SUM` >= 1024:

```
SELECT
    t1.recipient
FROM transfers AS t1
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM transfers t2
    WHERE
        t2.recipient = t1.recipient
        AND t2.amount >= t1.amount
) <= 3
GROUP BY t1.recipient
HAVING SUM(t1.amount) >= 1024
ORDER BY t1.recipient;
```

Comment: Excellent solution! How to understand the nested sub query within first WHERE? I try to figure it out but I can't find a good way to show what is going on inside.

Comment: Looks like there is a small bug. When trying `SELECT t1.recipient, t1.amount
FROM transfers t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transfers t2 WHERE t2.recipient = t1.recipient AND t2.amount >= t1.amount) <= 3;`  Only 2 records from 'William' was included